# Get a sharepoint web name from sharepoint site

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, spweb

```
spsite site =new spsite(/sites/gvr/);
spweb web=site.openweb();
```

I'm getting all my subsites here, like

```
/sites/gvr/test1
sites/gvr/test
```

I need only subsite name like test1 or test2.

Please let me know the approach or any other SharePoint properties available to get the name alone?

Answer (score 1):

use [SPWeb.Name](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spweb.name(v=office.12).aspX) to get the internal name or url name of the web

use [SPWeb.Title](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spweb.title(v=office.12).Aspx) to get the display name or title of the web